# Similarity between number list in range?

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

How do I define a maximum and minimum number for a range that is compared? For example I have the following movie ratings by Shane; [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5] and a list of ratings by Jaycee; [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], they are out of 5 stars. Pretend these are the .values() from a dictionary, and the movies are in order for each list.

When using the following functions:

```
from math import *

def square_rooted(x):

    return round(sqrt(sum([a*a for a in x])),3)

def cosine_similarity(x,y):

    numerator = sum(a*b for a,b in zip(x,y))
    denominator = square_rooted(x)*square_rooted(y)
    return round(numerator/float(denominator),3)

print cosine_similarity([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

The output is 1.0 when it should be near the low end of the ratio, probably around .5, as it's between 5 and 1. How would this be done?

Answer (score 2):

From your example:

```
numerator = 5*1*7 = 35
```

And

```
denominator = sqrt(5*5*7) * sqrt(1*1*7) = 5 * sqrt(7) * sqrt(7) = 35
```

That is why you got `1.0` and this makes sense if you consider the cosine similarity formula:

```
a.b = ||a|| ||b|| cos (theta)
```

Note that since you have `[5, 5, ..., 5]` and `[1, 1, ..., 1]` your two vectors point to the *exact same direction* in the 7-dimension coordinates. Thus, it has matching cosine similarity, which is `1.0`. `cos(theta)` is 1.0.

Comment: Then is there another method that would give an output of 0.0 to 1.0 based on similarity of numbers accurately?

Comment: Hmm, that would depend on what you mean by "similarity"... but it seems to me that what you want is a similarity independent from direction - only based on value. How would you like your value similarity to behave actually?

Comment: I was thinking a similarity rating based on the difference of the numbers, the higher the ratio, the higher the similarity

Comment: OK, then you could simply use bigger one as reference and divide the sum of them: `sum(y) / sum(x)` that will always give you value between 0 to 1, provided that the bigger one (x) in this example is not have zero summation (which will cause divide by zero error).